# Math domain error with calculating discriminate

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is solving quadratic equations that the user inputs with their a, b and c values. The issue is with my compute_discriminate function. I thought it was because you cannot take the square root of a negative number, so I said if d is negative, say there is no solution. However, I am getting an error in line 56, saying 
x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
ValueError: math domain error

Help with this situation would be extremely helpful, Python is new to me and I am wanting to get this to work!

Tried saying if d is negative, say there is no solution before defining x1 and x2.

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
import math


def evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x):
    f_of_x = a * (x ** 2) + (b * x) + c
    return f_of_x  # return the calculated result


print("Welcome to the Quadratic Solver for f(x)=ax^2+bx+c")
a = input("Enter Value for a:")
b = input("Enter Value for b:")
c = input("Enter Value for c:")
# cannot do math on string, convert to float
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
f_x0 = a * ((-b) / (2 * a) ** 2) + (b * (-b) / (2 * a)) + c


def print_sign(x):
    # check the sign if positive or negative
    return '+' if x > 0 else '-'


if a == 1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", "x**2 ", print_sign(b), abs(b), "x ", print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")
if b == 1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 ", print_sign(b), "x ", print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")
if c == 1:
    print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 ", print_sign(b), abs(b), "x ", print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")

x = input("Enter Value for x:")
x = float(x)

fx = evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x)
print("F" + "(" + str(x) + ")""=", str(fx))
temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait

x0 = -b / (2 * a)
x0 = float(x0)
if a > 0:
    print("f(x) has a minimum at " + str(x0) + " with a value f(x0)=" + str(f_x0))
else:
    print("f(x) has a maximum at " + str(x0) + " with a value f(x0)=" + str(f_x0))
temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait


def compute_discriminate():
    print("Solving for f(x) = 0")
    d = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
    if d < 0:
        print("No real solution.")
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
    print("Discriminant is", str(d))
    if d > 0:
        (print("Two Real Solutions", str(x1), "and", str(x2)))

    if d == 0:
        print("One real solution:", str(x0))



print(compute_discriminate())
```

Comment: I am thinking it is because of my if a=1 statements, maybe it is making it happen because of it happening when the value equals one.

Answer (score 0):

After you check if d<0 is true, you need to also return/exit the function, or else it will continue to execute.

```
d = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
if d < 0:
    print("No real solution.")
    return # Exit the function now
x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Untietled123 is absolutely right, or you could do this:

```
assert d>=0
```

assert means that the function has to be true 
otherwise, it raises an error

if you want to make it come with a message, you could do:

```
try:
    assert d>=0
except AssertionError:
    msg = ("no real solution")
    raise AssertionError(msg.format(__file__))
```

it is pretty handy in situations where there is a huge chunk of code after this and you want the code to end right when it come across that error.

this way you don't have to exit the loop or anything

also, in the end there

```
print(compute_discriminate())
```

you don't need to print the function, I guess you never realized cos you get an error every time before it is completed :)

hope it helps :)

here's a version where you can solve equations multiple times, I tweaked it a bit

Untietled123 is absolutely right, or you could do this:

```
assert d>=0
```

assert means that the function has to be true 
otherwise, it raises an error

if you want to make it come with a message, you could do:

```
try:
    assert d>=0
except AssertionError:
    msg = ("no real solution")
    raise AssertionError(msg.format(__file__))
```

it is pretty handy in situations where there is a huge chunk of code after this and you want the code to end right when it come across that error.

this way you don't have to exit the loop or anything

also, in the end there

```
print(compute_discriminate())
```

you don't need to print the function, I guess you never realized cos you get an error every time before it is completed :)

hope it helps :)

EDIT: here's a version where you can solve equations multiple times, I tweaked it a bit e.g got rid of the pauses, but you can still get them back if you want

```
import math

print('Credit to Adam Hermon from stack overflow')
'''asked a question, I fixed his code and now I'm using it '''
print("Welcome to the Quadratic Solver for")
print('f(x)=ax^2+bx+c')
done = False
while not done:
    a = input("Enter Value for a:")
    b = input("Enter Value for b:")
    c = input("Enter Value for c:")
    # cannot do math on string, convert to float
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    c = float(c)
    f_x0 = a * ((-b) / (2 * a) ** 2) + (b * (-b) / (2 * a)) + c


    def evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x):
        f_of_x = a * (x ** 2) + (b * x) + c
        return f_of_x  # return the calculated result

    def print_sign(x):
        # check the sign if positive or negative
        return '+' if x > 0 else '-'


    if a == 1:
        print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", "x**2 ", print_sign(b), abs(b), "x", 
        print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")
    if b == 1:
        print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 ", print_sign(b), "x ",                                 
        print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")
    if c == 1:
        print("\nFunction is: f(x)= ", a, "x**2 ", print_sign(b), abs(b), 
              "x", print_sign(c), abs(c), sep="")

    x = input("Enter Value for x:")
    x = float(x)

    fx = evaluate_quad_function(a, b, c, x)
    print("F" + "(" + str(x) + ")""=", str(fx))
    ##temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait

    x0 = -b / (2 * a)
    x0 = float(x0)
    if a > 0:
        print("f(x) has a minimum at " + str(x0) + " with a value f(x0)=" + 
            str(f_x0))
    else:
        print("f(x) has a maximum at " + str(x0) + " with a value f(x0)=" +  
            str(f_x0))
    ##temp = input("\nPress Enter to continue...")  # wait


    def compute_discriminate():
    ##    print("Solving for f(x) = 0")
        d = (b ** 2) - (4 * a * c)
        if d < 0 :
            print('No Real Solutions')
            return 'bad'
        x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        print("Discriminant(the stuff under the sqrt sign) is", str(d))
        if d > 0:
            (print("Two Real Solutions", str(x1), "and", str(x2)))

        if d == 0:
            print("One real solution:", str(x0))



    compute_discriminate()
    print('')
    print('Another one? Press enter')
    i = input('if not, type no')
    if i == 'no' or i == 'No' or i == 'NO':
        done = True
    else:
        print('Solving another equation:')
```